# Se mantienen los datos al instalar una app desinstalada

Tags: android, instalacion

Estoy desarrollando una app nueva en Android, con Android Studio. Para las pruebas utilizo un terminal físico y, ya me ha pasado varias veces, cuando añado una tabla a la Base de datos y elimino la app del terminal e instalo de nuevo con esta tabla, es como si al reinstalarse, se quedara con los datos que tenia antes de instalar y la nueva tabla no se crea. De hecho tengo los datos que tenia antes de desinstalar.

He intentado cambiar el nombre del paquete, ya que no me importa puesto que es una app nueva, pero da igual, cuando entro tiene los datos antiguos y no ha creado la nueva tabla en la Base de datos.

También he hecho clean antes de instalar por si se quedaran los datos cacheados, pero no hay forma.

La única forma en que he conseguido que se tratara como una app nueva ha sido creando un nuevo proyecto con otro nombre y otro paquete y copiando el código de una app a la otra.

Sabéis por qué ocurre esto y cómo se podría solucionar sin tener que crear un nuevo proyecto????

Antes esto no me pasaba. Desisntalaba la app y al volverla a instalar era como si no la hubiese instalado nunca, que es lo suyo.

Decir que el móvil está rooteado dado que la app necesita root

gracias

Comment: Intenta deshabilitar el AutoBackup, con la propiedad `android:allowBackup="false"` en el manifest.xml. En si, Google es quien automáticamente hace Backup de la data local del usuario, por lo que puede darse ese comportamiento.

Comment: Muchas gracias esa era la respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> cuando añado una tabla a la Base de datos y elimino la app del
>   terminal e instalo de nuevo con esta tabla

El problema que comentas es porque al re-instalar la aplicación nuevamente, esta ya contiene la estructura de la base de datos anterior.

Si deseas que esta estructura cambie a la nueva versión debes definir una nueva versión para la base de datos, esto lo puedes definir en la clase que extiende de `SQLiteOpenHelper`

```
    public class FeedReaderDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
        public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "FeedReader.db";

        public FeedReaderDbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }
    ...
    ...
 }
```

Pero esto implica que cambies constantemente ese valor cada vez que necesitas ver reflejado un cambio.

En este caso también tienes como opciones:

- Eliminar el caché de la aplicación desde los settings.

  o
- Eliminar la aplicación antes de volver a subirla.

> La única forma en que he conseguido que se tratara como una app nueva
>   ha sido creando un nuevo proyecto con otro nombre y otro paquete y
>   copiando el código de una app a la otra.

No es necesario llegar al extremo de cambiar tu package name, si lo anteriormente no funciona, probablemente tienes habilitada realizar una copia de seguridad de tu aplicación. Revisa tu `AndroidManifest.xml` y asegura que no este habilitada la copia de seguridad, por default esta deshabilitada pero si tienes la propiedad definida, deshabilitala de esta forma:

```
android:allowBackup="false"
```

Revisa:

**[Cómo habilitar e inhabilitar una copia de seguridad](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup#EnablingAutoBackup)**

> Las apps que se orientan a Android 6.0 (API nivel 23) o versiones
>   posteriores participan automáticamente en una copia de seguridad
>   automática. En tu archivo de manifiesto de la app, configura el valor
>   booleano `android:allowBackup` para habilitar o inhabilitar la copia de
>   seguridad.

Comment: Muchas gracias, efectivamente tenia     android:allowBackup="true"   He eliminado esta instrucción y ya me ha funcionado.  Perdonad la tardanza en contestar, pero hace tiempo que no había tocado el proyecto.  Muchas gracias de nuevo por la ayuda